# Migrating data from GCP (BIgquery) to Teradata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to query in GCP and migrate the result (1M rows) to Teradata since the BI team only has access to Teradata.
What would be the best way to complete this job?
This has to be done every month, so if there is any way to automate this, it would be perfect.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is an QueryGrid Connector from Teradata to BigQuery. With using this, you can access from Teradata directly objects residing in BigQuery. This would be the easiest way.
Alternatively you can use the GoogleCloud Storage as an intermediate storage, where both BigQuery and Teradata can access.